# change new line to break except last line in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can convert the "newlines" to the HTML line breaks using `nl2br($test)` command, but I want the command to convert all the newlines except the last one. I don't want any breaks after the last line. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: edit with your string and add more details, code as example

Comment: please use the search before asking a question. thank you.

Comment: @hakre that doesn't look like an obvious duplicate, as there are additional steps to answer *this* question

Comment: you got some advance with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

When you convert your string with `nl2br` and the function adds a `<br />` at the end of the resulting string; then you can just eliminate the last `<br />` with either `substr` or `rtrim` functions:

```
<?php
$string = "This\r\nis\n\ra\n\rtest\n\r";
$string = trim(nl2br($string));


echo $string;
echo "<br>\n";
echo substr($string, 0, -6);
echo "<br>\n";
echo rtrim($string, '<br />');

?>
```